# Google Chrome slow startup windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I have Windows 10 and recently my Google Chrome has a very slow startup but then it works fine afterwards. Each time I open Chrome, it happens. This issue is not just with my primary user but all my users, guest user, and incognito mode. 
I have tried the following steps:
- uninstalled and reinstalled google
- complete reset my windows 10
- made the user data folder 'default' to 'backup default'
- clear cache, history, etc.
- removed all extensions
- updated all drives
- netsh winsock reset
- issass.exe changes
- hardware acceleration changes
- reset chrome settings to default

Please help as even the google forum is not able to.